# Associating onClick function to dynamically created elements in a list

Tags: javascript, function, dynamic, inline, element

I have a list of words, and with each word there is a star icon attached (to bookmark the item). With the star, an inline `onClick` function is attached. All of these items are dynamiclly generated like this:

```
$('#bookmarks').append("<ul>"+"<p><strong>"+(key.replace(/\//g, ' / ')).replace(/\_/g, ' ')+"</strong></p>");
for (var dd in obj[key])
{
    var fname= key+"/"+obj[key][dd];
    if(!((String(obj[key][dd]).toLowerCase()).indexOf("README.md".toLowerCase()) != -1)) {
        if(!favs.includes(fname)) {
            current_fname = favs[fname];
            $('#bookmarks').append("<li><a target='_blank' href='/code/"+key+"/"+obj[key][dd]+"'>"+""+obj[key][dd]+"&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>" + "<i onclick=updateFavs(this,\'"+favs[fname] +"\') class='fa fa-star'></i><br></li>");
        } else {
            $('#bookmarks').append("<li><a target='_blank' href='/code/"+key+"/"+obj[key][dd]+"'>"+""+obj[key][dd]+"&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>" + "<i onclick=updateFavs(this,\'"+favs[fname] +"\') class='fa fa-star checked'></i><br></li>");
        }
    }
}
$('#bookmarks').append("</ul>");
```

Now, using inline functions in Chrome is not allowed.

So when I attach an id to the star like `id='myStar'` like this:

```
if(!favs.includes(fname)) {
    current_fname = favs[fname];
    $('#bookmarks').append("<li><a target='_blank' href='/code/"+key+"/"+obj[key][dd]+"'>"+""+obj[key][dd]+"&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>" + "<i id='myStar"+favs[fname]+ "' class='fa fa-star'></i><br></li>");
} else {
    $('#bookmarks').append("<li><a target='_blank' href='/code/"+key+"/"+obj[key][dd]+"'>"+""+obj[key][dd]+"&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>" + "<i id='myStar"+favs[fname]+ "' class='fa fa-star checked'></i><br></li>");
}
```

and associate an `onClick` function like this:

```
$("#bookmarks").on("click", "myStar", function () {
    console.log("You clicked the button");
});
```

the `onClick` function gets called as many times as there are words in the list and gets associated to all the stars in the list instead of being associated with the current star. What should I do in such a situation?

Comment: Can't see `myStar` class, but **no need to attach a `click` event listener for every `append`**. Do it once before adding the elements to DOM since you are doing delegation anyways.

Comment: @gurvinder372 edited the question showing how `myStar` is being attached. And how to attach click event once, please elaborate?

Comment: Just write the same code before creating all the `li`s.

Comment: Nope, still getting called numerous times.

Comment: Share a working snippet and replicate your issue.